# Tetrahedral pancake problem game.

Tags: puzzle, card-games, sorting

I am currently playing around making a little puzzle game and was looking for some input from people better at maths than me. It is based on the pancake problem.

You have a stack of $8$ "pancake" cards. Each has a letter $a-h$ and you must get them in order.
Each pancake has $4$ sides ($1-4$, each side of the card is divided in $2$ horizontally).

To flip $a$)cut the stack $b$) take the top pancake of the lifted section $c$) progress it to its next face $d$) put it on top of the bottom section. Repeat for every card in the lifted section

This is like flipping pancakes in the burnt pancake problem but instead of $2$ states (burnt/unburnt) it has $4$ (burnt, crispy, chewy, perfect)

To make it a game I have used a 9th card to track $16$ turns. After which you score each pancake in the correct position (I think it would be virtually impossible to get a perfect stack)
I don't really have any specific questions I was just looking for thoughts from math minded folks.

Comment: Reminder : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting

Comment: I think I should of added that your aim is to get all pancakes perfect side up (like the burnt pancake problem).